# RSpec asking for user input

Tags: ruby, rspec, user-input

I have two questions. Given the ruby code below, what kind of tests would your write in RSpec and how would you avoid when running tests to keep get asked for the user input? I have tried many ways such as:

1. allow($stdout)
2. allow(Kernel)
3. stub(:gets)
4. STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("exit")
5. allow($stdin).to receive(:gets).and_return('no_gets')
6. allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to receive(:gets).and_return('exit')

But non of the above worked. In test kept asking me for the user input.

```
 class EchoApp
   def greeting
     while(true)
      puts "Say something:"
      user = gets.chomp
      break if user == 'exit'
    end
   return "Goodbye!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestions should work actually. But there is another option.

```rb
orig_stdin = $stdin 
$stdin = StringIO.new('exit') 
assert(EchoApp.new.greeting,'Goodbye!')
# Or 
expect(EchoApp.new.greeting).to eql('Goodbye!')
$stdin = orig_stdin
```

Let me know if this does not work.